# How to capture stdout of a running process redirected to /dev/null

Tags: files, pipe

I want to capture `stdout` of running process whose `stdout` is being redirected to `/dev/null`. I tried using system call `fcntl()`, however the moment I close fd "1", it was being allocated for other files as it was lowest available fd number.

Any ideas how to lock given fd and reassign to other file?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can capture that by using proc filesystem:

`$ cat /proc/<PID>/fd/1`

Comment: Can you add an example of how this works?

Comment: $ cat /proc/<PID>/fd/1 works when written stdout to a file but doesn't work when stdout sent to /dev/null

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use `gdb` to do that.  See several of the answers to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin). Seems like that might come from [this blog article](http://etbe.coker.com.au/2008/02/27/redirecting-output-from-a-running-process/).

Comment: right, I'm looking for the lines of code to execute while process connected to gdb

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using reredirect (https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect/).

```
reredirect -m /dev/null <PID>
```

You can restore initial output of your process later using something like:

```
reredirect -N -O <M> -E <N> <PID>
```

(`<M>` and `<N>` are provided by previous launch of reredirect).

reredirect `README` also explains how to redirect to another command.